# Spring Boot AntMatchers vs @PostAuthorize usage

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, rbac

I'm tasked with implementing RBAC(Role-Based Access Control) in the REST API I'm working on.

What puzzles me is that when I use in my Security class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, in configure method antMatchers, the Authorisation is working correctly, but when I dispose of antMatchers and try to replace them by @PostAuthorize on top of an endpoint, RBAC fails to work.

That's my configure method from a class extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .rememberMe()
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilterAfter(new JwtTokenVerifierFilter(), JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/user").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/hello").hasRole(ApplicationUserRole.ADMIN.name())
            .anyRequest()

            .authenticated();

    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();/*REQUIRED FOR H2-CONSOLE*/
}
```

Which works fine.

Thats by annotarion on top of an endpoint that shoud be authorized, but is not.

```
@PostAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping("/hello")
String hello(){

    return "hello";
}
```

What am I doing wrong, that it is not workind correctly?

Comment: To enable annotation processing you need to add `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try annotating your security config class with the below annotations?

Something like this.

```java
@Configuration  
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)  
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {  
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {}  
}
```